# purchase oblique / 45 degrees imagery of european cities

Tags: imagery

I am looking to purchase oblique / 45 degrees imagery of some european cities but I am not able to find a supplier that cover most countries.

Does anybody know any or have expirience with this kind of product?

Comment: A central parameter that you haven't mentioned is the spatial resolution that you need. It matters quite a lot.

Comment: 0.3 - 0.5 meters

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are aware of the costs involved in acquiring data like that, it shouldn't be a problem for your local reseller of either AirBus or DigitalGlobe data to arrange for such a dataset as you require to be acquired. All of the relevant satellites are capable of acquiring oblique imagery.
The data that you need is most likely not already acquired, but it should be possible. However, depending on your actual data needs, you may actually require multiple sets of oblique images (one from each direction), which in turn is going to be reasonably expensive, but again, I see no reason that it shouldn't be possible (given enough money).

Now, who your local reseller is not a question that can be answered easily.